# tweey api search not getting all tweets

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to search tweets related to a whiskey brand for my project and i am not able to get more than 27 tweets and when i am searching only english tweets i am getting only 10 tweets, i do have sandbox access of full archive search access ,so it's not the problem of searches that are recent but something else, i have also tried writing search query in different formats (e.g query='(whiskey brand-name) OR brand-name') so that it will search for both brand name and brand name with whiskey in tweet but still not getting more than 10 tweets, my code is like this

```
     auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    # set access token and secret
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    # create tweepy API object to fetch tweets
    api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    tweets=api.search_full_archive(query=query,label=label,maxResults=100)
```

on twitter there are many tweets related to this query but tweepy api not giving those.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, the mistake i was doing that if you don't mention fromDate parameter in search api , it will take only past 30 days, so just initialize fromDate with the date from when you want tweets or just the start date of twitter which is 2006 1st March